# Jquery Autocomplete Gem- Passing params into database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, autocomplete

I'm a Rails newbie and I'm struggling to use the Jquery Autocomplete gem.  I can get the autocomplete to work fine, but I cannot pass the id of the element into my database.  No matter what, the params show the autocompleted name, thus the ID field in the database is 0.  I have the action set up in the controller as follows:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
 autocomplete :nhood, :name
```

The route also seems to work fine, since the autocomplete is functioning properly.  The error is somewhere in the form, and I have tried a ton of variations and nothing works.  The goal is to pass the neighborhood id, wich corresponds to the autocompleted neighborhood name, into a 'plans' table. Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@plan, :url=> groups_createplan_path) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :nhood_id %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :nhood_id, autocomplete_nhood_name_groups_path,
:update_elements => {:id => '#id_element'}, :size=>50 %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

I started with variations of

```
  :id_element => '#some_element', such as :id_element => '#nhood_id', or just
  :id_element => '#id'
```

but nothing seemed to work.  I'm pretty lost, and I think I've followed the gem documentation closely, so I don't know where the error is.

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

If someone can help, it would be much appreciated.  I'd be happy to provide more information if needed.  Thank you

UPDATE: 
I should also note that firebug shows the response, which includes the "id" that I want: 
    {"id":"36","label":"Soulard","value":"Soulard"}

Hence my question is really just how do I get that "id" to pass in the params hash, instead of the "label"?  I keep getting "soulard" to pass, and not "36."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation trying to link a course id to a course timetable.  What worked for me was to pass the id in a hidden field.

```
<%= f.label "Course Number" %><br />
<%= f.autocomplete_field :course_number, autocomplete_course_name_department_timetables_path, :update_elements => {:id => "#timetable_course_id"}%>
<%= f.hidden_field :course_id%>
```

So what might work for you could be

```
<%= f.label :nhood_id %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :nhood_name, autocomplete_nhood_name_groups_path, :update_elements => {:id => '#plans_nhood_id'}, :size=>50 %>
<%= f.hidden_field :nhood_id %>
```